# Download war from Oracle weblogic console

Tags: weblogic, war

Could you please help me downloading the war file from Oracle Web Logic console. I have lost all my files only way i have left with it.

I have follwing path mentioned in the console

> **Path** - / u01/ FMW/ Oracle/ Middleware/ user_projects/ domains/ cxm_domain/ servers/ AdminServer/ upload/ PSSM1. war

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Wm6.jpg)

But dont know how to access this path. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need access to the server where the Weblogic instance is running. You can SSH or FTP to that server (you need a username/password for that) and then follow that path.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download war file from console but you can get it from either admin or manager server. You need to go to that particular location where you've deployed code in managed server or you need to go to the location where you kept war file for deploy on admin node. For that you need to login to that physical machine and get it